# composer require maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar in laravel 6.6

Tags: php, laravel-6

I am using laravel 6.6 I am try to create event calander using  fullcalander 
I am getting following error :

```
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.22|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.25|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.26|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.33|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v6.6.0, required as ^6.2) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.6.0].
- Installation request for maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar 1.3 -> satisfiable by maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar[v1.3.0].
```

**After i Tring to this code **

```
"repositories": [
    {
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/rayblair06/laravel-fullcalendar.git"
    }
    ],
```

After I Use This code packeg is succesfully instrall.Calander class can't define

```
      `Call to undefined function MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\str_random() (View: C:\Users\Chamod\Desktop\SIS poject new\SIS\resources\views\calender.blade.php)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar` package has no support for laravel 6.x at the moment.

There are some [open pull request](https://github.com/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar/pull/153) which would make it compatible with laravel 6.x, until then you could try and use the forked repository. But it is up to the maintainer to accept the pull request and make the original package compatible with laravel 6.x